# (1)TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'collections.OrderedDict'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid (2)

Tags: python, pandas

I have created some simple code that copies and pastes all Excel files in directory in same folder with same formats and columns name....

The Excel file is a type of .xlsx as this file contains 3 sheets, so now I have three sheets called GSM, UMTS, and LTE and this sheet name is the same name in all sheets. Now all I need to copy the data in sheet GSM, data in UMTS, and data in LTE to it's every own data to the new sheet, and drop duplicates.....

As I need also the change the color of the columns or keep it as the same style as like from source, and text style, etc...

So Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

basepath = r'C:\Users\mwx825326\PycharmProjects\MyExcelCombine\myCDD Combine'
files = list(filter(lambda x: '.xlsx' in x, os.listdir(basepath)))
alldf = pd.DataFrame()
for f in files:
    df= pd.read_excel(f"{basepath}/{f}",encoding='latin-1', sheet_name=None)
    alldf = pd.concat([alldf,df]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)

alldf.to_excel("1- CDD Total12.xlsx")
```

and this is my error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/mwx825326/PycharmProjects/MyExcelCombine/CombineTool.py", line 9, in <module>
    alldf = pd.concat([alldf,df]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
  File "C:\Users\mwx825326\PycharmProjects\MyExcelCombine\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py", line 255, in concat
    sort=sort,
  File "C:\Users\mwx825326\PycharmProjects\MyExcelCombine\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py", line 332, in __init__
    raise TypeError(msg)
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'collections.OrderedDict'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid

Process finished with exit code 1
```

and this is my sheets looks like

```
mydir = (os.getcwd()).replace('\\', '/') + '/'

gsm_cdd_total = pd.read_excel(r'' + mydir + '1- CDD Total.xlsx' ,sheet_name='GSM')
umts_cdd_total = pd.read_excel(r'' + mydir + '1- CDD Total.xlsx' ,sheet_name='UMTS')
lte_cdd_total = pd.read_excel(r'' + mydir + '1- CDD Total.xlsx' ,sheet_name='LTE')

gsm_generate = pd.read_excel(r'' + mydir + 'GUL CDD20191008021501.xlsx' ,sheet_name='GSM')
umts_generate = pd.read_excel(r'' + mydir + 'GUL CDD20191008021501.xlsx' ,sheet_name='UMTS')
lte_generate = pd.read_excel(r'' + mydir + 'GUL CDD20191008021501.xlsx' ,sheet_name='LTE')
```

and this my excels `xlsx` looks like it have three main sheets ever sheet have it's own data[xlsx looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ltx0N.png)

So If any one knows how to update data relate to every sheet and how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

When you run *read_excel* whith *sheet_name=None*, the result is a **dictionary**
(*sheet_name*: *DataFrame*).

So:

- don't use *df* here as the destination variable (this is misleading),
- add another loop iterating over keys / dataframes (using *items*)
  or over dataframes alone (using *values*),
- within this loop, you can merge each DataFrame (read from the current
  sheet)
  with *alldf*.

Something like:

```
for f in files:
    # Here the result is a dictionary of DataFrames
    dct = pd.read_excel(f"{basepath}/{f}",encoding='latin-1', sheet_name=None)
    # Process each DataFrame from this dictionary
    for df in dct.values()
        alldf = pd.concat([alldf,df]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```

**Another possibility:** If each your Excel file has only a **single**
sheet to read from, you can run your original code, but **without**
*sheet_name* parameter (its default value is **0**, meaning
*read only from the first sheet and return a DataFrame*).

Comment: first thanks a lot for your support, you mean that to create a `Dataframe` for every sheet, then loop on this sheet?.....
I am glad to give me some specific example if you could :)
All I need, I have multiple excel files with same content and the same columns, as from this excel files, there's a master excel file contains the same look for data and the other excel file with the same also look but with new data, so I want to concatenate all this new data files to the master file

Comment: thanks for your help but your code mean that is merging all sheets in one sheet, that's I didn't mean really, all I neeed... I have three different sheets `GSM`, `UMTS`, and `LTE` so now every sheet have it's own data, I want to merge this data refers to every sheet data, for example , the data in sheet `GSM` should be in `GSM`, the data in `UMTS` should be in the `UMTS`, and the data in `LTE` should be in `LTE` :)

Comment: So I see that passing *sheet_name=None* (as you did) is wrong as then **all** sheets are processed in one go. Probably you should program 3 separate loops, computing the result for each telephony system, passing respective sheet names.