# TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'list'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, types

I have a list of 10 dataframes named d0, d1, d2,...d9. All have 3 columns and 100 rows.

```
d0.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 100 entries, 0 to 99
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------  --------------  -----  
 0   0       100 non-null    float64
 1   1       100 non-null    float64
 2   2       100 non-null    float64
dtypes: float64(3)
memory usage: 2.5 KB
```

I want to merge all dataframes so that I can have 3 columns and 1000 rows and then convert it into an array.

```
s1=[d0,d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,d7,d8,d9]
s2=pd.concat([s1])
```

The above code throws error:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'list'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid

type(s1)
list
```

I used the solution suggested in [pd.concat in pandas is giving a TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'str'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61573099/pd-concat-in-pandas-is-giving-a-typeerror-cannot-concatenate-object-of-type-c?rq=1) ; however, got the above error.

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58482715/1typeerror-cannot-concatenate-object-of-type-class-collections-ordereddict

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`s1` is already a list. Doing what you did called pd.concat with a list of a list with DataFrames, which pandas doesn't allow. You should do it like this instead:

```py
s2=pd.concat(s1)
```

Comment: throws this error "TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'str'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid"

Comment: One of the items inside s1 is a string. You have to figure out what you are doing wrong because the answer I gave correctly concatenates dataframes

Answer (score 0):

@ThomasQ is correct that the concatenation of lists of *dataframes* should work. I had the same issue and checked the type of my *dataframes*, finding that one was a list of *pandas series*, not a proper `df`.

So I first turned the list of series into a dataframe:

`df3=pd.concat(f_to_add, axis=0)`

Then I repeated the concatenation on a list of two valid dataframes:

`df3=pd.concat([df2, df3], axis=0, sort=False)`

The `axis`, of course, depends on whether you want to join your data on rows or columns.